# Building libxml2 with static c runtime library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, libxml2

I am wondering if there is anyway to build libxml2, on Windows, with static crt. I do not want to deal with msvcr90.dll issues.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building on Visual Studio, you can set it to statically link the runtime by going to Project Settings, then C/C++ -> Code Generation.